# Salesforce License difference in two developer pro sandbox

Tags: refresh

I have got two developer pro sandboxes, one I had refreshed 11th March and the other I refreshed on 24th March, the one which was refreshed 11th march are having 12 salesforce licenses, the other one is having 27 salesforce licenses. How is this possible??

Answer (score 2):

The license types and counts in a sandbox are set to match those in the production org at the time of sandbox creation/refresh.

If additional licenses were provisioned to the production org between March 11 and March 24, that would explain the difference.

If you need to update the license counts to match production without refreshing the sandbox, you can log a customer support ticket to request that, but specify why the sandbox refresh is not an option.

Comment: Great Thomas thank you. Yeah i checked production, the licenses were indeed increased. Thanks